# JavaScript - get an attribute's value from HTML element

Tags: javascript

I want to display 'a' character as alert

HTML:

```
<span id="demo" name="a" onclick="validateForm1id1()"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function validateForm1id1() {
        var x = document.getElementById("demo").name;
        alert(x);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In most browsers, DOM element typically only reflect standard attributes as DOM properties (there are some exceptions). *name* isn't a standard attribute of [*span* elements](http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-span-element), so you'll need to use *getAttribute*.

Answer (score 0):

As @robg says in the comments:

> In most browsers, DOM element typically only reflect standard attributes as DOM properties (there are some exceptions). name isn't a standard attribute of span elements, so you'll need to use getAttribute

You need to use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to get the `name` attribute from your `span`.

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute("name");
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sF62K8Y7Yan1R8K27NuI?p=preview) to show it working.

If you are attempting to store arbitrary data in your html elements, take a look at the `data-*` attribute. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

> HTML5 is designed with extensibility in mind for data that should be associated with a particular element but need not have any defined meaning. data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as classList, non-standard attributes, extra properties on DOM, or setUserData.

You can then do

HTML:

```
<span id="demo" data-name="Span name using data-name" onclick="validateForm1id1()">Click me</span>
```

JS:

```
function validateForm1id1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo").dataset.name;
    alert(x);
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3KTul5iFBqfiZLkrFaBT?p=preview) showing the `data-*` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code. You need to get the attribute 'name'.

```
function validateForm1id1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute('name');
    alert(x);
}
```